# yarn install --check-files giving me error output that I don't understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I have a Ruby on Rails project that I'm deploying on a freshly set up server.

I run the command `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` and it says:

```
========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================
```

So I run the command it tells me to run, and ultimately it fails with a few errors that I don't really understand:

```
  g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/src -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/zlib -I/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++1y -std=c++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
In file included from /home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8.h:30,
                 from /home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
  452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      remove_cv
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
  452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      remove_cv
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                                  ^
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:452:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
  452 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~
../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/binding.cpp:284:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
      |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/binding.cpp:320:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
      |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/node.h:806:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  806 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
      |                                           ^
/home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/node.h:840:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
  840 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
  358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ubuntu/vendsmartsolutions/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1038-aws
gyp ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/vendsmartsolutions/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/vendsmartsolutions/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/vendsmartsolutions/node_modules/node-sass/build'
Build failed with error code: 1
```

I looked it over several times and I really have no idea what any of it means. This project runs fine on my development VM.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the problem with the version of nodeJS.

I tried node v15 and it works for me, while v16 would fail.

Also, node-sass is deprecated. You should change another library to use.

Comment: Was having this issue in a Dockerfile extending `node:alpine`, updated to `node:15-alpine` and it worked again. Does seem to be a node version issue for sure.

Comment: @LuckyWind_sck what other library are you suggesting?

Comment: I don't really have any suggestion. I remembered that what I did is changing my node version. Maybe you can get some help in node-sass repository.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241196/error-no-template-named-remove-cv-t-in-namespace-std-did-you-mean-remove/67242989#67242989) is what solved for me and [@S.Goswami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205719/yarn-install-check-files-giving-me-error-output-that-i-dont-understand/67243754?noredirect=1#comment119747372_67243754). Please try that solution first.**

If the above solution doesn't work, it might be worth trying what is recommended [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374#issuecomment-605663098), but unfortunately that didn't work for me, or for [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205719/yarn-install-check-files-giving-me-error-output-that-i-dont-understand/67243754?noredirect=1#comment119746533_67243754), but it could be worth a try if the above solution doesn't work. Here's an outline of the solution that worked for some, but **not** everyone:

1. Delete `yarn.lock`
2. There's a directory in the root of your rails app called `node_modules` - delete it. NOTE: if you use sublime text, it won't show directories that simply ["house source control information and various binary output files"](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/missing-files-in-folder-tree/31145/3) (lesson learned). Open your app **in finder**, find `yourapp/node_modules/` and delete it.
3. Run `spring stop` (I didn't need to do this, but others have recommended it, and it won't hurt).
4. Now simply reinstall your node modules with `yarn install`. *But*, if this step errors, try using `yarn install -std=c++17` as found in the help from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241196/error-no-template-named-remove-cv-t-in-namespace-std-did-you-mean-remove#comment118854482_67241196) and @Scheff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242426/5783745)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work with Archlinux's node while trying to install node modules for Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @S.Goswami can you try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242989/5783745) instructions instead (I will update the above answer as I now know a lot more about the issue than I did back then)

Comment: @S.Goswami please let me know how you go.

Comment: Downgrade isn't an option for a lot of people. There are whole lot of soname bumps, and if I downgrade, I get: `node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.68: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Sure, I can copy current libicui18n   , rename and paste it in /lib/ and maybe some other dozen of them and make it running, but not a good idea. Definitely nvm is the only option imo.

Comment: @S.Goswami the linked solution uses NVM so I think it should take care of that?

Comment: Yes, with NVM installed node v15, and it worked flawlessly!

Comment: @S.Goswami brilliant! thanks for the update. I'll make it very obvious in this answer that it worked!

Answer (score 2):

**node-sass** doesn't support Node v16 yet. So for now downgrade Node to v15 will fix these errors. For further updates visit [sass/node-sass#3077](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3077)